# issue after pulling code [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]

Tags: php, symfony

I just pulled some code on my prod environment. The changes is very little (I have added a {{ form_widget(meeting.text) }} in one of my html.twig page.
Nothing else.

Know when my server is down and the error I get when I load the page app_dev.php is the following:

```
ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 84:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.bundles_metadata".
```

I do not use any parameterbag.php in my code. I can't even find it! Same thing for the kernel.bundles_metadata. I cannot find it in my code.

Here is the full error:

```
in ParameterBag.php line 84
at ParameterBag->get('kernel.bundles_metadata') in bootstrap.php.cache line 1897
at Container->getParameter('kernel.bundles_metadata') in FrameworkExtension.php line 713
at FrameworkExtension->getValidatorMappingFiles(object(ContainerBuilder)) in FrameworkExtension.php line 665
at FrameworkExtension->registerValidationConfiguration(array('enable_annotations' => true, 'enabled' => true, 'static_method' => array('loadValidatorMetadata'), 'translation_domain' => 'validators', 'strict_email' => false), object(ContainerBuilder), object(XmlFileLoader)) in FrameworkExtension.php line 114
at FrameworkExtension->load(array(array('translator' => array('fallback' => 'en'), 'secret' => '******', 'router' => array('resource' => '/var/www/html/BDLCapital-v3/app/config/routing.yml', 'strict_requirements' => null), 'form' => null, 'csrf_protection' => null, 'validation' => array('enable_annotations' => true), 'templating' => array('engines' => array('twig')), 'default_locale' => 'en', 'trusted_proxies' => null, 'session' => null, 'fragments' => null, 'http_method_override' => true), array('router' => array('resource' => '/var/www/html/myAPP/app/config/routing_dev.yml', 'strict_requirements' => true), 'profiler' => array('only_exceptions' => false))), object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 59
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 102
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 568
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2436
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2215
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2246
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 22
```

If you have any idea that would help me a lot!

I am using symfony 2.7.

EDIT: when I try to do sudo php app/console cache:clear I get the following message:

```
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.bundles_metadata".
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I have seen on a website that this come after symfony 2.7.22 so I changed my compose.json to symfony/symfony = 2.2.22 and ran composer udapte and my website is up. But I do not understand where the issue came from

Comment: This happens when one of your services uses a parameter like `%kernel.bundles_metadata%` that is not defined anywhere. You might want to check your paramters.yml (maybe you forgot to copy a new parameter from dist file) or your .env. Alternatively you can specifiy this parameter in your services.yml depending on how much it depends on your current environment.

Comment: @StaP please, don't use Symfony `2.2.22` - that's a pretty old version that is out of support for long time.

Comment: Try to run `composer run post-install-cmd` read more about it here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21646